# OneToOne field in django default

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Please help. I have a model:

```
class Book(core.BaseModel):
    book_link = models.OneToOneField('self',  default = "",  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book_name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=250)
```

I want to set 'self' in field book_link that will return in this field - book_name or Book Model object.

But when I create new Book object - Django  shows me in column "book_link" all book names which I can choose and save new object. I want that when I created new object it will authomatically save for this object this name!

Comment: It is not clear to me why you have a `book_link` here. This looks like a parent-child relation, but conceptually it makes not much sense that a book belongs to another book.

Comment: I need it for generate new book with new number!It will be new book with old data  old book but with new number.And I want to have a book_link which has link between old book and new book

Comment: @KenIst: so you basically want a way to copy data from another (already existing) book. In that case the model should *not* contain such link. It is the form logic that should handle this, not model logic.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I want that each book consider this book_link like id, using the way to  create field OneToOne field - link 'self':) please just explain me how in admin panel , when I save object -  this field save as an autho-created)and return book name data in this field 'book_link')?

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question, you want to create something like a linked list of books. To do so, first do not use one to one field unless each book is only and only linked to one book. To link one object to itself, you can use the name of model in string format.

And also note the way you had provided default was faulty, It is better to make it nullable with `null=True`.

My recommended model will be this:

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    book_link = models.ForeignKey(to='Book', null=True,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="linked_books")
    book_name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=250)
```